# rigorous proof in first year multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Hi could anyone help producing a proof for the following?

If $f(x,y)$ is continuous on a closed and bounded region $R$, then $f$ has both an absolute maximum and an absolute minimum on $\mathbb{R}$.

(I am reviewing some multivariable calculus I did not have a chance to learn in first year...)

Comment: Do you know anything about compactness?

Comment: yes. I have done analysis and some introductory functional analysis. But how does that help?

Comment: From your wording I assume that $\Bbb R$ in your question does not mean all of the real numbers, which is what $\Bbb R$ usually means. You probably should use a different symbol for your region.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n$ be an arbitrary sequence in the domain of $f$. By Bolzano-Weierstrass in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ whose limit is $x$ which is in the domain of $f$. By continuity, $f(x_{n_k})$ also converges. So $f(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence which converges to $f(x)$. Since $x_n$ was arbitrary, the range of $f$ is sequentially compact.

Now by Bolzano-Weierstrass in $\mathbb{R}$, the range of $f$ is closed and bounded. Let $M$ be the supremum; since it is the supremum you can choose a sequence inside the range which increases to $M$; so by closedeness $M$ is in the range. The analogous argument shows that the infimum is in the range as well.

Comment: thanks. What books cover proofs of this kind?

Comment: @math101 I think pretty much any undergrad real analysis text should cover this. Often these have titles like "advanced calculus"; I've heard good things about a book by Fitzpatrick with this title. I used *The Way of Analysis* by Strichartz, which is an enjoyable read but a terrible reference.